# FetchMode Subselect not running on Set attribute

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, jpa

My class has a `Set` collection attribute and it's marked with `@Fetch(value = FetchMode.SUBSELECT)`. But it is still loading the attribute with different queries instead of just one with subselect

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "NPRO_USUARIOS")
public class User implements Serializable {
   //Method and atributes supressed
   @ManyToMany(cascade = { CascadeType.ALL })
   @JoinTable(name = "NPRO_USUARIOS_AREAS", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "id_usuario"), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "id_area"))
   @Fetch(value = FetchMode.SUBSELECT)
   private Set<Area> listAreas;
   // ...
}
```

And this is the log :

```
Hibernate: select user0_.id_usuario as id_usuario1_22_0_, user0_.activo as activo2_22_0_, user0_.email_usuario as email_usuario3_22_0_, user0_.fecha_ultimo_acceso as fecha_ultimo_acces4_22_0_, user0_.matricula_usuario as matricula_usuario5_22_0_, user0_.nombre_usuario as nombre_usuario6_22_0_, user0_.observaciones as observaciones7_22_0_, user0_.usuario_modif as usuario_modif8_22_0_, user1_.id_usuario as id_usuario1_22_1_, user1_.activo as activo2_22_1_, user1_.email_usuario as email_usuario3_22_1_, user1_.fecha_ultimo_acceso as fecha_ultimo_acces4_22_1_, user1_.matricula_usuario as matricula_usuario5_22_1_, user1_.nombre_usuario as nombre_usuario6_22_1_, user1_.observaciones as observaciones7_22_1_, user1_.usuario_modif as usuario_modif8_22_1_ from npro_usuarios user0_ left outer join npro_usuarios user1_ on user0_.usuario_modif=user1_.id_usuario where user0_.id_usuario=?

Hibernate: select listareas0_.id_usuario as id_usuario1_23_0_, listareas0_.id_area as id_area2_23_0_, area1_.id_area as id_area1_5_1_, area1_.activo as activo2_5_1_, area1_.clase_doc_telesap as clase_doc_telesap3_5_1_, area1_.fecha_modif as fecha_modif4_5_1_, area1_.nombre_area as nombre_area5_5_1_, area1_.observaciones as observaciones6_5_1_, area1_.id_sociedad as id_sociedad8_5_1_, area1_.tipo_dato as tipo_dato7_5_1_, area1_.usuario_modif as usuario_modif9_5_1_ from npro_usuarios_areas listareas0_ inner join npro_maestro_areas area1_ on listareas0_.id_area=area1_.id_area where listareas0_.id_usuario=?
```

Any idea why is not just executing one query?

Comment: I am not an expert and this seems to be expected behavior. you might have a look at https://www.solidsyntax.be/2013/10/17/fetching-collections-hibernate/#:~:text=Hibernate%20FetchMode%3A%20SUBSELECT&text=Customer%20Laura%20Steel-,Hibernate%3A%20select%20invoices0_.,id%20as%20id1_1_1_%2C%20...&text=A%20SUBSELECT%20generates%20one%20query,fetch%20all%20the%20Invoice%20collections.

Comment: No, as you can see in your link the expected behaviour is to do one query with subquerys, not n+1 querys

Comment: It is saying `A SUBSELECT generates one query to load the Customers and one additional query to fetch all the Invoice collections. ` or my understanding is wrong ? Does it not exactly happening in your case ?

Comment: Yeah, sorry, you are rigth. I was confused. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So your main query for `User` is the one that you will always have. When you use `SUBSELECT` fetching, it will trigger one additional query. If you were using `SELECT`, it would trigger one query for every N `User` objects that you fetched, where N is the batch size. If you fetch only a single user, as it seems to be the case, you could also use `SELECT` which would produce a similar query.

The difference is, a `SELECT` query will query by owner id whereas a `SUBSELECT` query, will embed the original query into the query to fetch the collection. Depending on how complex the original query is, it might be better to use `SELECT` with a proper batch size to avoid executing the complex query parts again. But these performance aspects have to be considered on a case by case basis.